# Using angular's ng-include with django's static files

Tags: angularjs, django, static, include

I'm using django to render my main templates. However, I want to reduce code per template using angular ng-include tags. I've configured angular to work with square brackets using the $interpolateProvider and also configured django's static files correctly (other static files work well), so no conflicts should accur.

When I'm trying to:

```
<ng-include src="{% static 'add_medication_views/general_tab.html' %}"></ng-include>
```

I get and error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] ...
<!-- ngInclude: undefined -->
```

'general_tab.html' is just a simple html text.
What am I missing here? I have searched in this subject but could not find any solution to this.
Thanks before

Comment: If django's static actually includes the html file contents that's not what ng-include is expecting in the src attribute it just expects the path to the html file to load the contents of.

Answer (score 1):

Put django's template tags in your src in quotation marks.

```
<ng-include src="'{% static 'add_medication_views/general_tab.html' %}'"></ng-include>
```